# mostrar datos de una consulta mysql en input text

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

buenos días estoy tratando de hacer un tipo buscador por rut el cual consiste en que el usuario ingresa el rut y se desplegan los valores del usuario en los input text de un formulario ejemplo: nombre: felipe , email:felipe@gmail.com etc hasta el momento me funciona bien, pero al desplegar en un

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    $sql="SELECT usuario.rut,nombres,apellidos,email, genero, anexo , area.nombre as area ,  tipo_usuario.nombre as tipo FROM usuario, area,  tipo_usuario WHERE usuario.rut = area.rut_Usuario and usuario.idTipo_Usuario = tipo_usuario.idTipo_Usuario and rut=?";
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$Codigo);
    $stmt->bind_result($rut,$nombres,$apellidos,$email,$genero,$anexo,$area,$tipo);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      echo $rut."*".$rut."*".$tipo."*".$nombres."*".$apellidos."*".$email."*".$genero."*".$anexo."*".$area;
    }
}else{
    echo "Error en la consulta: ";
}

    function CargaDatosUsuario(){
                var dataString="Codigo="+document.getElementById('rut').value;                 
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
                else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                  {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                         {
                                 if(!(xmlhttp.responseText == 0)){
                                         var resultado = xmlhttp.responseText.split("*");
                                         document.getElementById('rut').value = resultado[0];
                                         document.getElementById('rut2').value = resultado[1];
                                         document.getElementById('tipo_usuario').value = resultado[2];
                                         document.getElementById('nombre').value = resultado[3];
                                         document.getElementById('apellidos').value = resultado[4];
                                          document.getElementById('email').value = resultado[5];

                                        document.getElementById('genero').value = resultado[6];

                                        document.getElementById('anexo').value = resultado[7];
                                        document.getElementById('area').value = resultado[8];
                                 }
                         }
                  }
                url_php = 'consultas/obtenerUsuario.php';  
                                   //metodo,url a enviar,asincrona, si es  asincrona no detiene la pagina a la espera de respuesta  
                xmlhttp.open("POST",url_php,true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send(dataString);

        }
```

Comment: La duda ha quedado cortada y no queda claro lo que necesitas. Por favor editala para poder ofrecerte una solución.

Comment: me acabo de dar cuenta no se porque me corta la pregunta

Comment: podrias tambien agregar parte de tu codigo html el formulario de donde recibe los resultados